# Notification library in javascript

Tags: javascript

Some weeks ago I found a small JS notification library like [notify.js](http://www.notifyjs.com/), I've googled for 30 minutes but I can't find it again.

It's a small library with the examples in top, left and a list between 5&10 examples in his homepage.

Help, hints are appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have a look at : [jQuery UI Notify Widget](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-notify/)
Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of http://notifyjs.com/, it's been updated and feedback would be appreciated. What are you looking to achieve exactly ?